# How to build correct JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Today I faced the problem that I can’t correctly form JSON.
The «collection» of the data to JSON looks like this:

```
SELECT json_agg((   
            json_build_object(
                'id_product', 0,                
                'product_name', 'Sprint',       
                'sprint_is_expired', null,
                'scale', 
                    json_build_object(
                        'queue',        (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 7),
                        'in_progress',  (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 8),
                        'closed',       (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status IN (9,12))
                    ),
                'period_begin', (SELECT to_char(date_start, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint),
                'period_end', (SELECT to_char(date_end, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint)
            ),
            json_build_object(
                'id_product', 0,                
                'product_name', 'Sprint',       
                'sprint_is_expired', null,
                'scale', 
                    json_build_object(
                        'queue',        (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 7),
                        'in_progress',  (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 8),
                        'closed',       (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status IN (9,12))
                    ),
                'period_begin', (SELECT to_char(date_start, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint),
                'period_end', (SELECT to_char(date_end, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint)
            )
        )) INTO var_result;
```

The output is like this:

```
[{"f1":{"id_product" : 0, "product_name" : "Sprint", "sprint_is_expired" : null, "scale" : {"queue" : 0, "in_progress" : 2, "closed" : 9}, "period_begin" : "09-01-2020", "period_end" : "17-01-2020"},"f2":{"id_product" : 0, "product_name" : "Sprint", "sprint_is_expired" : null, "scale" : {"queue" : 0, "in_progress" : 2, "closed" : 9}, "period_begin" : "09-01-2020", "period_end" : "17-01-2020"}}]
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
[{}, {}, {}]
```

And not like that:

```
[{f1:{}}, {f2:{}}, {f3:{}}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular query you can do:

```
SELECT json_build_array(   
            json_build_object(
                'id_product', 0,                
                'product_name', 'Sprint',       
                'sprint_is_expired', null,
                'scale', 
                    json_build_object(
                        'queue',        (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 7),
                        'in_progress',  (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 8),
                        'closed',       (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status IN (9,12))
                    ),
                'period_begin', (SELECT to_char(date_start, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint),
                'period_end', (SELECT to_char(date_end, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint)
            ),
            json_build_object(
                'id_product', 0,                
                'product_name', 'Sprint',       
                'sprint_is_expired', null,
                'scale', 
                    json_build_object(
                        'queue',        (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 7),
                        'in_progress',  (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status = 8),
                        'closed',       (SELECT COUNT(id_sup_sprint_detail) FROM all_cases_in_last_sprint WHERE id_cur_status IN (9,12))
                    ),
                'period_begin', (SELECT to_char(date_start, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint),
                'period_end', (SELECT to_char(date_end, 'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM last_sprint)
            )
        ) INTO var_result;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni